# Auto cast of void* argument in function pointer

Tags: c

Following code works fine, however I was wondering if this is valid use of rule that void* is compatible with any other pointer

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int foo;
} SomeStruct_t;

typedef void(*SomeFunction_t)(void* ptr);

void bar(SomeStruct_t* str) {
    printf("%d\n", str->foo);
}

void teddy(void* anyPtr) {
    SomeStruct_t* str = (SomeStruct_t*)anyPtr;
    printf("%d\n", str->foo);
}


int main()
{
    SomeFunction_t functPtr = (SomeFunction_t)bar;
    SomeStruct_t data = {.foo = 33};
    functPtr(&data);
    
    functPtr = teddy;
    functPtr(&data);
    return 0;
}
```

Question is, should I use `bar` or `teddy` variant? I prefer `bar` but I'm not sure if for some corner cases this might lead to hard to detect problem.

Comment: Calling a function through a pointer with a different signature (as in "`bar` variant") is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not valid:

```
SomeFunction_t functPtr = (SomeFunction_t)bar;
```

Because you're casing a function pointer of type `void (*)(SomeStruct_t*)` to type `void (*)(void*)` and subsequently calling it though the casted type.  The function pointer types are not compatible because the parameters are not compatible.  This triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

While a `SomeStruct_t *` can be converted to a `void *`, that conversion can't happen because the casted function pointer prevents it.  There's no guarantee that `SomeStruct_t *` and `void *` have the same representation.

Using the function `teddy` which matches the function pointer type is safe.  Also, you don't need to cast the parameter to `SomeStruct_t *` inside the function because conversions to/from `void *` don't require one in most cases.

Comment: _"There's no guarantee that `SomeStruct_t *` and `void *` have the same representation."_ +1 for this alone. This is an incredibly common misconception. It's not even guarenteed that `sizeof(SomeStruct_t *) == sizeof(void*)`.